# Android Studio: Annotations are not allowed here error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Don't know why this error is coming. I have used the same logic of adding `@Override` in my previous apps (Which I learned from Udacity).

I'm currently doing the [Multiscreen Apps](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-multi-screen-apps--ud839) course. Do let me know if anyone else have completed this course or having the same error.

Here's what I wrote:

```
//Find the view that shows family category
TextView family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family);

//Send a clicklistner on that view
family.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{
    @Override //here's the error
    public void onClick (View v){

    // create a new intent to open the {@link FamilyActivity}
    Intent familyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FamilyActivity.class);

    // start the new activity
    startActivity(familyIntent);
}
});
```

Thanks,
Kvaibhav01.

Comment: what is the error msg?

Comment: show the complete code if there is no privacy issue

Comment: what java SDK do you use? And what is your java language level? In Java 5 it was not allowed to add the @Override-annotation to an overrridden interface method.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
  family.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

As I remember textView doesn't have onClickListener, it has onTouchListener and maybe this's a problem